# In Django, how do I filter where language column = "null"?

Tags: python, mysql, database, django

MyTable.objects.filter(where language column = null)

How can that be done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
MyTable.objects.filter(language__isnull=True)
```

[Link to documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/models/querysets/#isnull).